# Mac OS X Credential Provider equivalent

Tags: macos

Is there an equivalent API for Mac OS X of the CredentialProvider API under Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's quite late to answer the question I hope it helps some one who is trying to find answer to same question. In MacOS it is called [Authorization Plugin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_plug-ins/using_authorization_plug-ins). In MacOS authorization is done basing on authorizationdb which has policies you add a policy to the authorization policy database, it can refer to any number of plug-ins(authorization plugin). Each plug-in includes one or more authorization mechanisms, where a mechanism is a code module that performs one step in the authorization process. All these policies need to agree and then the user logs in.